# Valid signature not found while deploying sencha application package(.app) to iPad device

Tags: ipad, html, sencha-touch-2

I want to deploy a sencha application to iPad device. I am reffering the following link.
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/native_packaging

By following the deployment steps(mentioned in above link), I am able to run the package on simulator but unable to deploy it on the iPad device. As we drag the .app to iTunes or the xCode organizer, it gives me an error "Valid signature not found". I had mentioned the correct certificate alias in the config file.

Please suggest how to resolve it.
Thanks